# assign number in sequential order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column (mycolumn) in a table (dbo.mytable) that is completely blank, I want to assign a sequential number starting at 1340000 to all rows in dbo.mytable.

Comment: starting at 1340000 and ordered by what criteria? and should this number be assigned for future rows too (identity column) or just for the existing ones (update)? This is quite unclear.

Comment: i'd strongly suggest you investigate the other answer to this question. the identity property is an ideal solution and once you add it, you don't have to worry about it ever again (unless you run out of numbers at 2.1 billion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Row_Number` and `CTE`

```
;with cte as
(
select seq = row_number()over(order by (select null))-1,*
   from mytable
)
update cte 
   set mycolumn = seq + 1340000
```

Comment: @KevinM This worked *now*; what happens when you add a new row to the table?

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER table mytable drop column mycolumn
ALTER table mytable add mycolumn int identity(1340000,1)
```